# Ant load properties from pattern

Tags: java, ant

In ant, I need to load a set of `.properties` files based on a pattern.
I tried:

```
<property>  
    <fileset includes="${propertiesDir}/*.properties"/>
</property>
```

but it doesn't work because `<property>` doesn't support nesting.

How can i load properties from files matching a pattern?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`concat`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task to concat all your properties files to a big temporary properties file, and the use [`property`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) with this big temporary properties file as attribute.

Make sure to use fixlastline="true" with the concat task to make sure each file ends with a new line character.

Example :

```
<target name="init">
    <concat destfile="temp/bigPropertiesFile.properties" fixlastline="true">
        <fileset dir="${propertiesDir}" includes="*.properties"/>
    </concat>
    <property file="temp/bigPropertiesFile.properties"/>
</target>
```

Comment: ah ok. so, should I use: <property file="${list}"/>
and then i define the list as a comma-separated list of `.properties` file paths?

Comment: No. Use the concat task to concatenate all your files (not the file names).