# How to load Ant properties from property files on the command line?

Tags: ant, properties, build

I have two property files [`one.properties` and `two.properties`]. I want to dynamically load the property files into my Ant project from the command line.

My build file name is build.xml.

Command line:

```
> ant build [How do I pass the property file names here?]
```

Comment: You want to create the files or you want to load the files?

Comment: I want to run the property file using ant build. I have created two property file but dunno how to run from cmd. I am runing now -> ant build. This will run the build.xml file and the property file i mentioned inside the build file, but I have multiple property file i need to pass property file name dynamically in the ant command build.

Answer (score 26):

## [Loading property files from the command line](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)

```
ant -propertyfile one.properties -propertyfile two.properties
```

Individual properties may be defined on the command line with the `-D` flag:

```
ant -Dmy.property=42
```

## Loading property files from within an Ant project

### [LoadProperties Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html)

```xml
<loadproperties srcfile="one.properties" />
<loadproperties srcfile="two.properties" />
```

### [Property Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)

```
<property file="one.properties" />
<property file="two.properties" />
```

### [Match property files using a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983439/ant-load-properties-from-pattern)

[JB Nizet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) solution combines [concat](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) with [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html):

```
<target name="init" description="Initialize the project.">
  <mkdir dir="temp" />
  <concat destfile="temp/combined.properties" fixlastline="true">
    <fileset dir="." includes="*.properties" />
  </concat>
  <property file="temp/combined.properties" />
</target>
```

Comment: Thaks for your respond.I feel you misunderstood my question. I need to run via 'cmd' and need to pass property file name dynamically. pls advice!

Comment: @Muthukumar, I expanded my answer to show how to pass the names of properties files on the command line [Specify properties files on command line].

Comment: In windows you might need to add quotes, "-Dmy.property=42"

Answer (score 0):

Making a build [condition](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) such that if Required System parameters are provided for build then only allowing for the next target else build gets fail.

```
 Pass CMD: ant -DclientName=Name1 -Dtarget.profile.evn=dev
 Fail CMD: ant
```

```xml
<project name="MyProject" default="myTarget" basedir=".">
    <target name="checkParams">
        <condition property="isReqParamsProvided">
            <and>
                <isset property="clientName" /> <!-- if provide read latest else read form property tag -->
                <length string="${clientName}" when="greater" length="0" />
                <isset property="target.profile.evn" /> <!-- mvn clean install -Pdev -->
                <length string="${target.profile.evn}" when="greater" length="0" />
            </and>
        </condition>
        <echo>Runtime Sytem Properties:</echo>
        <echo>client              = ${clientName}</echo>
        <echo>target.profile.evn  = ${target.profile.evn}</echo>
        <echo>isReqParamsProvided = ${isReqParamsProvided}</echo>
        <echo>Java/JVM version: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
    </target>

    <target name="failOn_InSufficentParams" depends="checkParams" unless="isReqParamsProvided">
        <fail>Invalid params for provided for Build.</fail>
    </target>

    <target name="myTarget" depends="failOn_InSufficentParams">
        <echo>Build Success.</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

@see also: [Replace all tokens form file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60264842/5081877)